# A-Frame "Building a Basic Scene" Issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, aframe

I've recreate Basic Scene in simple .html document and it dont work properly in Chrome, only in Firefox Nightly. Need some help, thnks.

Chrome: 
  [doesn't load textures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WXOK.png)
[image]

---

Nightly: 
[everythig is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8W26.png)
[image]

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise there is not much we can do to help you.

Comment: Sry, my bad
`<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="boxTexture" src="https://i.imgur.com/mYmmbrp.jpg">
  </a-assets>
  <a-box src="#boxTexture" position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2"></a-box>  
<a-sky color="#522"></a-sky>
  <a-light type="ambient" color="#445451"></a-light>
  <a-light type="point" intensity="2" position="2 4 4"></a-light>
</a-scene>
  <body>
</html>`

Comment: Hmm. A-Frame should be injecting `crossorigin` flag on those images. It works for me on Chrome. Console issues?

Comment: @ngokevin there's screenshot of errors
[link](http://imgur.com/a/kBXCE)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are experiencing a browser inconsistency when accessing files from your computer directly (i.e. the address starts with `file://` instead of `http://` or `https://`).

If you open [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2u4nqr7e/), you will see the texture both in Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome is stricter than Firefox when it comes to loading data from your local filesystem. To work around this, you can [run a local webserver](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255) or use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com), [Codepen](http://codepen.io) or [Glitch](http://glitch.com).